# How can I inherit partner address fields (city, state_id, country_id) and their behavior?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I have a module that contain a form with information about a certain service (discharge date, leaving date, name of company...) but I need to add fields like on `res.partner` that contain and autofill addresses (street, city, state_id, country_id). How can I inherit and add these fields on my custom module?

Comment: are you want to get the same partner address or a new address

Comment: a new one, just want to inherit the field structure and autofill functionality

Comment: What exactly do you mean by autofill functionality. I didn't know of such feature on Odoo partners.

Comment: your question isn't clear enough. especially the part of autofill, do you want to select an existing user from a dropdown and then have those address fields in your form automatically populated from that user's already existing data?

Answer (score 0):

```
country1_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Country')  
country_id = fields.Many2one(related='country1_id.country_id', string='Country' )
state_id = fields.Many2one(related='country1_id.state_id', string='State')
```

you can inherit like this in your python file

```
views/.xml file:
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @David Martin you can add first Many2one field of res.partner object

```
partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Partner")
country_id = fields.Many2one('res.country', related='partner_id.country_id', string="Country")
street,street2,state.. so on
```

and add these fields in your view file so whenecer you select any partner in partner_id field you will get country,and street and street auto populated in your fields.